# Spark convert column filed type which is in Json to multiple rows or nested rows

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have json like below, this is just one cut of data.  so actual zipped json has lot if these kind of data

```
 {
    "filed1": "value1",
    "filed2": "value2",
    "data":"{\"info\":[{\"type\":[\"Extra\"],\"value\":9},{\"type\":[\"Free\"],\"value\":8},{\"type\":[\"Actual\"],\"value\":100}]}",
    "code": "0000"
}
{
    "filed1": "value3",
    "filed2": "value4",
    "data":"{\"info\":[{\"type\":[\"Extra\"],\"value\":1001}]}",
    "code": "0001"
}

{
    "filed1": "value5",
    "filed2": "value6",
    "data":"{\"info\":[{\"type\":[\"Actual\"],\"value\":90},{\"type\":[\"Free\"],\"value\":80}]}",
    "code": "0003"
}
```

when I read this is in spark the data column is read as String, So I need to parse and make a columns like below , Here each row needs to be converted to multiple rows

```
filed1   filed2  code  type    Value
value1   value2  0000  Extra   9
value1   value2  0000  Free    8
value1   value2  0000  Actual  100
value3   value4  0001  Extra   1001
value5   value6  0003  Actual  90
value5   value6  0003  Free    80
```

I have written below udfs but I dont know how to create multiple row for a inputted single row

```
val getTypeName = udf((strs:String) => {
 // parse json and return types
  })

val getValue = udf((strs:String) => {
 // parse json and return values
  })

val df = spark.read.json("<pathtojson">)
val df1 = df.withColumn("type", getTypeName("data")).withColumn("value", getValue("data"))
```

but with logic I can get only single row, I want this to converted two number of rows as per my data fields

Answer (score 0):

The function you are looking for is called `explode`.  Basically you want to write a UDF that parses your JSON, and spits out an array of nested rows.  Then you call explode on that column.  Explode will take a column with multiple values and create a new row for each value (duplicating the values in the other columns).  For example:

```
case class DataRow(filed1: String, filed2: String, data: String, code: String)

val df = Seq(
    DataRow(
        "value1",
        "value2",
        "{\"info\":[{\"type\":[\"Extra\"],\"value\":9},{\"type\":[\"Free\"],\"value\":8},{\"type\":[\"Actual\"],\"value\":100}]}",
        "0000"
    ),
    DataRow(
        "value3",
        "value4",
        "{\"info\":[{\"type\":[\"Extra\"],\"value\":1001}]}",
        "0001"
    )
).toDF 

case class NestedRow(row_type: String, value: Int)
def processJsonFn(json: String): Seq[NestedRow] = {
    // ... Parse json ...
    val parsed = Seq(NestedRow("Extra", 9), NestedRow("Actual", 100))

    parsed
}
val processJson = udf(processJsonFn _)

// Convert string json to nested rows
val df2 = df.withColumn("data", processJson($"data"))

// Explode them
val df3 = df2.withColumn("data", explode($"data"))

// Flatten structure
val df4 = df3.select($"filed1", $"filed2", $"data.row_type" as "type", $"data.value" as "value", $"code")

df4.printSchema
df4.show
```

Outputs this:

```
root
 |-- filed1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- filed2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- value: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- code: string (nullable = true)


scala> df4.show
+------+------+------+-----+----+
|filed1|filed2|  type|value|code|
+------+------+------+-----+----+
|value1|value2| Extra|    9|0000|
|value1|value2|Actual|  100|0000|
|value3|value4| Extra|    9|0001|
|value3|value4|Actual|  100|0001|
+------+------+------+-----+----+
```